# Different Behaviour between ++ and += 1

Tags: unity, c#

```
void AddItem(Item item)
{
    int indexOfDuplicateItem = System.Array.IndexOf(itemsInInventory, item);

    if (indexOfDuplicateItem > -1)
    {
        quantityText.text = (stackSize[indexOfDuplicateItem] += 1).ToString(); // Problem occurs here
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numSlots; i++)
        {
            if (itemsInInventory[i] == null)
            {
                itemsInInventory[i] = item;
                GameObject itemImage = Instantiate(itemImagePrefab, slots[i].transform);
                itemImage.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = item.itemSprite;
                quantityText = slots[i].GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
                stackSize[i] = item.itemQuantity;
                quantityText.text = stackSize[i].ToString();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

The indicated line behaves differently if I write `quantityText.text = (stackSize[indexOfDuplicateItem]++).ToString();`

I'm a relative beginner to both C# and Unity. Can someone explain why the behaviour of `(stackSize[indexOfDuplicateItem]++).ToString()` is different from `(stackSize[indexOfDuplicateItem] += 1).ToString()`?

using += 1 to increment behaves correctly, but ++ ends up being the correct answer - 1.

Comment: For syntax questions, don't neglect to google it / [search Stack Overflow first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598681/can-someone-explain-the-operator) - they have good coverage of common questions about language fundamentals.

Comment: Indeed, this is a very basic issue with programming syntax (not that it is a *bad* question for a programming Q&A, but it has nothing to do with game dev, itself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour given the usual syntax for `++`, which has been around since the language B (circa 1969):

- `variable++`  is a **"post-increment" operator**, ie. "Return to me the current value of the variable, then increment that variable *afterward*"

  So an expression containing this construct gets evaluated with the *old* value of the variable, before it was incremented.

  This is useful in a loop where you want to ensure the *next* use of a variable is incremented, eg...

  `int p = 0;
  for(y = 0; y < height; y++)
      for(x = 0; x < width; x++)
         pixel_buffer[p++] = GetPixelColor(x, y);`

  This loop will write to pixel_buffer[0] first, then each subsequent index in turn.
- `++variable` is a **"pre-increment" operator**, ie. "Increment the value of the variable *before* returning it, then return to me its new value"
- `variable += 1` is an (augmented) **assignment expression**. When it's evaluated, the whole expression gets run (incrementing the variable), then the resulting value of the variable is treated as its return value. So it behaves similarly to `++variable`

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely because of how the `++` operator works. The `++` operator works in two steps:

1. Returns the value if the variable
2. Increments the variable

This means that when you do `stackSize[indexOfDuplicateItem]++` it first returns `stackSize[indexOfDuplicateItem]` THEN increases the value by 1. It's the same as writing this:

```
quantityText.text = (stackSize[indexOfDuplicateItem]).ToString();
stackSize[indexOfDuplicateItem] += 1
```

This is a small test case:

```
>>> int i = 5;
>>> Console.Write(i)
5
>>> Console.Write(i++)
5 // STILL 5!
>>> Console.Write(i)
6 // Now 6!
```

To circumvent this you could put the `++` *before* like so: `++stackSize[indexOfDuplicateItem]`. This will increment the value by 1 and then return the value. This should give the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
int i = 0
strings[] myArray = ["a","b","c","d"];

...

Debug.Log(myArray[i++]); // Evaluates i first, which is zero -> log = "a"
                         // Then add 1 to i

Debug.Log(myArray[i++]); // Evaluates i first, which is 1 -> log =  "b"
                         // Then add 1 to i
```

Now we can also do ++ on the left side

```
int i = 0
strings[] myArray = ["a","b","c","d"];

...

Debug.Log(myArray[++i]); // add one to i first, then evaluate i -> log =  "b"


Debug.Log(myArray[++i]); // add one to i first, then evaluate i -> log =  "c"
```